# Does anyone know how following eigenvalue problem lead to such solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

This is from a non-English paper and the entire paper is quite long so I will snip out the relevant bits I need help with. It is about the study of a nonlinear differential equation called Davey-Stewartson equation.

*The question is long only because I had a lot of matrices and some explaining to do. But my question itself is purely related to calculation issues*

First we have operators $L_1,L_2$ defined as follows

> $L_1=D+Q$ and $L_2=i \partial_t+J(\partial_y-\partial_x)-2Q(\partial_y-\partial_x)+W$ where,($q:=q(x,y,t)$ is some function, which is a solution to the Davery Stewartson equation. It shall not be directly relevant to my query. $U,V$ are also pre-specified functions which will not be needed now)
>
> $J=\begin{pmatrix} 
>     1       & 0 \\
>     0     & 1  
> \end{pmatrix}$
>
> $Q=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 
>     0       & q \\
>     q^*     & 0  
> \end{pmatrix}$
>
> $W=\begin{pmatrix} 
>     V       & -\sqrt{2}q_y \\
>     -\sqrt{2}q_x^*     & -U  
> \end{pmatrix}$
>
> $D=\begin{pmatrix} 
>     \partial_x       & 0 \\
>     0     & \partial_y  
> \end{pmatrix}$

Now using these $L_1,L_2$ here is what it says in the paper for the differential equation it talks about(I have translated to English below)

> The differential equation $1.1$ can be written as a Lax pair $[L_1,L_2]=0$. Now, if we introduce a $2 \times 2$ Jost function $M(x,y;k)$ where $k$ is a spectral parameter, we consider the eigenvalue problem
>
> $$L_1M(x,y;k)\begin{pmatrix} 
>     e^{iky}       & 0 \\
>     0     & e^{-ikx}  
> \end{pmatrix}=0$$
>
> Among the solutions of this equation, if we denote those analytic in the upper half of the complex $k$-plane as $M^+$ and those analytic in the lower half as $M^-$, we integrate each factors in the above equation once to obtain
>
> $$M_{11}^{\pm}=1- \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \int_{-\infty}^xqM_{21}^{\pm}dx'$$
>   $$M_{12}^{\pm}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \int_{\mp\infty}^xqM_{22}^{\pm}e^{ik(x-x')}dx'$$
>   $$M_{21}^{\pm}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \int_{\pm\infty}^yq^*M_{11}^{\pm}e^{ik(y-y')}dy'$$
>   $$M_{22}^{\pm}=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \int_{-\infty}^yq^*M_{12}^{\pm}e^{ik(y-y')}dy'$$
>
> We have used $|k| \rightarrow \infty$ then $M \rightarrow I$ where $I$ is the identity matrix.

My question: how were these obtained? Here is my understanding,

> I do not know what a Jost function is(wikipedia tells me it's a Wronskian of a Schrodinger equation...but shouldn't it be a one-dimensional scalar, and not a matrxi?), but seemingly, it looks like it is $M=\begin{pmatrix} 
>     M_{11}       & M_{12} \\
>     M{12}     & M_{22}  
> \end{pmatrix}$
>
> $$L_1M\begin{pmatrix} 
>     e^{iky}       & 0 \\
>     0     & e^{-ikx}  
> \end{pmatrix}=(D+Q)M\begin{pmatrix} 
>     e^{iky}       & 0 \\
>     0     & e^{-ikx}  
> \end{pmatrix}=0$$
>
> But since $D$ is a differential operator, I do matrix multiplication $M\begin{pmatrix} 
>     e^{iky}       & 0 \\
>     0     & e^{-ikx}  
> \end{pmatrix}$ first. Then, rearranging the terms (those under the differential operator and those not), I get the following.
>
> $$\begin{pmatrix} 
>     \partial_x(M_{11}e^{iky})       & \partial_x(M_{12}e^{-ikx}) \\
>     \partial_y(M_{21}e^{iky})     & \partial_y(M_{22}e^{-ikx})  
> \end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 
>     -qM_{21}e^{iky}       & -qM_{22}e^{-ikx} \\
>     q^*M_{11}e^{iky}     & q^*M_{12}e^{-ikx}  
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> Now, take the element in $a_{11}$ of the matrices. Namely, $\partial_x(M_{11}e^{iky})=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}qM_{21}e^{iky}$. So,
>
> $$e^{iky}\partial_x(M_{11})=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}qM_{21}e^{iky}$$
>
> I divide both sides by $e^{iky}$ and integrate thus obtain
>
> $$(M_{11})=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int qM_{21}dx'$$

What I don't understand is, the actual answer is $(M_{11})=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{\infty}^xqM_{21}dx'$. Where did the $1$ come from? I think it's because $M \rightarrow I$, BUT I cannot clearly explain it by steps as to how it came to that.

> Now, for $\partial_x(M_{12}e^{-ikx})= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}qM_{22}e^{-ikx}$. Unlike the previous case, we must use chain rule and becomes,
>
> $$\partial_x(M_{12})e^{-ikx}-ike^{-ikx}M_{12}= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}qM_{22}e^{-ikx}$$

For this, the answer is $M_{12}^{\pm}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \int_{\mp\infty}^xqM_{22}^{\pm}e^{ik(x-x')}dx'$. I cannot see why $e^{-ikx}$ does not disappear like it did in $M_{11}$ by straightforward calculation.

Basically, I wish someone to show me the steps to obtain the correct answers as in the paper only for $M_{11},M{12}$. The other two must be analogous to it.

I know the explanation has been tedious, but the actual content isn't too complicated, I think. It would be great if someone could help me out.